# Why Azure Function with Timer trigger suddenly stops being triggered?

Tags: azure-functions

I have several Azure Function Apps with few functions each. Today, for second time, one of the function apps just stopped triggering the functions (just after 11 pm UTC, when there was no release or any interaction with the function settings).

The function is supposed to run every minute. The trigger is set to `"0 * * * * *"`.

The monitor log looks like this:

[image]

The topmost one is when I manually disabled and enabled the function (I couldn't stop it as there was no such button in the UI, the function was in some kind of a broken state).

All functions are on Consumption plan.

Anybody knows what can cause this and how to prevent it? It fails silently, there are no logs or alerts.

Comment: Did you inspect the logs and diagnostics? , there might be an exception prevention function execution

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. I think there are a *LOT* of different reasons for this and you have to troubleshoot them one by one. Like your case, I didn't have crashes or errors. It just stopped.

[image]

So, first I checked the duration of the functions (see picture) wasn't longer than my function. My timer was `"0 */2 * * * *"` so I'm good there.

The I discovered that I had exceeded my Daily Usage Quota.
[image]

That is protection against a "denial of wallet" attack. So I'll probably upgrade once I have a better look at the costs.

Note that this may not be the answer to *your* problem, but it's worth noting in this tread as its' something that people troubleshooting could overlook.

Answer (score 0):

With the same schedule, I observed and didn’t get any break in the executions of every minute - hosted in Consumption Plan:

[image]

As per my research, few points to be checked are:

1. Check the diagnostic logs as suggested by the user @*peterbons*.
2. Also, check the options Performance, Transactional Search in the Application Insights for the count of requests, exceptions that are logged during the executions:

[image]
3. Check the troubleshooting steps given in the similar issue of Q&A Forum #[548467](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/548467/azure-function-timer-trigger-suddenly-stops-firing) from the MSFT User @*MayankBargali-MSFT*.